# Sql query to insert datetime into table when user buy online product

Tags: mysql

SQL query to insert date time into table when user buy online product.
in my project i want o fix data and time when user buy online product

```
    insert into prod_ordr (order_date, order_time) values (current_date(), current_time())
      select
      c.buyer_id,
      p.comp_name,
      p.usr_address,
      p.city,
      p.state,
      p.pincode,
      p.contact_one,
      c.prod_id,
      c.qty,
      c.prod_barter_val

      from add_to_cart c join usr_profile p
      on c.buyer_id = p.usr_id
      where p.usr_email ='sunny@yahoo.com';
```

Comment: here I am trying this code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [MySQL NOW() function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) for this

Comment: using now() we can show current time and date but whenever we execute query every time we get change current date and time.I want to fix the date and time when user buy the product.